# heroku postgres Group by query on indexed columns takes more than 2 seconds to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, group-by, heroku-postgres

On heroku postgres my group by query is taking more than 2 seconds, is it normal? How can I optimize this further? Both columns are indexed So I was assuming that it should run faster.

The query is,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE(SELECT COUNT(*), context, call_type FROM call_tasks GROUP BY call_tasks.context, call_tasks.call_type );
```

query plan and analyze:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.08..11500.84 rows=12 width=11) (actual time=35.395..2545.426 rows=7 loops=1)
   Group Key: context, call_type
   ->  Index Only Scan using index_call_tasks_on_context_and_call_type on call_tasks  (cost=0.08..10338.79 rows=774677 width=11) (actual time=0.022..1480.729 rows=781076 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 43682
 Planning time: 0.085 ms
 Execution time: 2545.464 ms
(6 rows)
```

I am using hobby basic database.https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best you can get, further improvements can only be made by improving the hardware:

- Faster CPU for faster aggregation.
- More memory to keep everything in RAM.

Other than that, if you are happy with an approximate result, you could use a materialized view that gets updated regularly.